# Launching a Perl script without output

Tags: perl, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I'm making a script (`Perl` or `shell`) that launches a second `Perl` script. The script that it's launching has thousands of lines of output. So basically I want to make a script that launches another script without any output - and if possible run it within a `screen` session and then exit the script (yet keep the other running in the `screen`)? How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you launch your script direct output to *[/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null).* To make a script run in the background use the `&` symbol. For example the follow will show nothing in the console and run in the background...

```
echo hi > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Wont this keep the first script hanging until the other dies/exits though?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run in `screen`, you have to create a `screenrc`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "screen  my_perl_program" >  /tmp/$$.screenrc
echo "autodetach on" >>  /tmp/$$.screenrc
echo "startup_message off" >>  /tmp/$$.screenrc
screen -L -dm -S session1 -c  /tmp/$$.screenrc
```

Then you can restore it with `screen -S session1`